# Down Votes Received at 1 Reputation

Tags: support

Idle curiosity here:  Do users at 1 rep who receive down votes have to make up that rep in order to have net positive rep?

For example:  New user asks a question which is down-voted 5 times.  The same user then asks another question which receives 5 up-votes.  What amount of rep does this user have after the second question?

Comment: IIRC rep can't go below 1.  Users at 1 rep are therefore invincible to downvotes!  :)

Comment: In terms of reputation, sure. Not so much in terms of question/answer bans ;)

Comment: A user can retract his downvote on one of your posts and thus make your reputation increase from 1 to 3. This has been considered negligible by the SE team and thus they have been unwilling to fix it.

Comment: @damryfbfnetsi Oh, I didn't know that. Are there any references to that? Seems like a pretty weird logic flaw that should be fixed to me ;)

Comment: @damryfbfnetsi Also, if you downvoted a post of someone who was at 1 rep, but the post gets an upvote later, you can undownvote and redownvote (if it is within 5 minutes of the original vote or the post has been edited since) to knock the poster down by 2.

Comment: Reputation never drops below 1. So if you're planning on attracting downvotes, better do it quickly while you're at 1. The order matters: 10 downvotes + 4 questionUpvotes = +20, while 4 questionUpvotes + 10 downvotes = 0.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisCorbett if reputation can't fall below 1, wouldn't your second example be equal to 1 rather than 0?

Comment: There's a difference between "should be fixed" and "worth fixing." They *could* track who's downvotes reduced points by adding a pointsDeducted column to the existing table of who downvoted what.
But then, instead of storing two ints per record when you store that table, you're storing two ints and a bool (or three ints). You've increased byte-aligned storage by 50% on a table that *must* be cached as it is referred to every page load, just to fix a bug that isn't being (can't be!) exploited effectively anyway.

Comment: @TRKemp: Well, sure, but I was showing the differential. The first example gives you +20 rep (i.e. you get to 21 total) while the second example gives you 0 (i.e. stay at 1).

Comment: They should let the reputation go negative, and display "1" for anyone with a reputation <= 1. That way, a user in this situation has to dig out of the hole, but we can keep calling them a 1-rep user for whatever feelings-related reason we currently don't let them go negative.

Answer (score 75, accepted):

> Do users at 1 rep who receive down votes have to make up that rep in order to have net positive rep?

No, they don't. We don't maintain a "negative surplus", so to speak.

So, if a question by such a user gets 5 downvotes, they will be at 1 rep. If it then gets an upvote, they will be at 6 rep.

> For example: New user asks a question which is down-voted 5 times. The same user then asks another question which receives 5 up-votes. What amount of rep does this user have after the second question?

After the 5 downvotes, they will have 1 rep. If then they get 5 upvotes on another question (or even the same one), they will have reputation of 26 (5 rep for upvote * 5 upvotes + 1 original rep).

See [How does "Reputation" work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7237/how-does-reputation-work) for details.

Comment: Per your edit regarding the same question being upvoted:  The user would have 26 rep even if the question itself had 0 net votes?

Comment: @MichaelMcGriff - the score? Yes. Score == number of upvotes - number of downvotes. What is important is the sequence of events. Say the 5 upvotes happened first (so 26 rep after the upvotes), then 5 downvotes - the resulting reputation would be 16 (-2 per downvote). The score would still be 0, the split of votes would still be 5/5, but the resulting reputation would be different.

Comment: Ah yes, I see now.  I'd also forgotten that upvotes and downvotes were weighted differently.  Thank you for your answers.

Comment: *"We don't maintain a "negative surplus", so to speak"* - that sounds like something a politician would say (well, maybe they would decorate it further as "inverted surplus" or similar). Isn't it usually called a deficit? (I'm from the US, and I think we have one of the biggest).

Comment: The moral of the story is that if you come across a really terrible question then wait a while for that dubious/pity upvote to appear before submitting your downvote.

Comment: What if the downvoters remove their downvotes in the end? Will OP get +2 for it?

Comment: @totymedli - yes.

Answer (score 13):

As per the [help documentation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation):

> All users start with one reputation point, and reputation can never drop below 1.

So no, the minimum you can hit is one rep point. If you get downvoted and you only have one, you stay at one. Obviously there are lots of cases where someone will be upvoted on a question, then downvoted several times; that leads to something like `1 + 5 - 2 - 2 - 2 - 2 -> 1`.

I think this is, at least in part, a way to let new users get used to the site without being permanently scarred by a single, terrible question. Although I could be wrong.

Comment: 6 - 8 = 1? **Mind Blown**

Comment: I didn't mean any offense.  I actually like your example.

Comment: @jmstoker no, no, no offense taken. Sorry if my comment sounded otherwise. I've deleted it. The guy last night was just very, well, we'll go with "persistent." Such is such, though.

Comment: `1 -2 -2 -2 -2 -2 -2 +5 = 6` **mind blown** :D

Comment: Stack Exchange is not commutative:D

Answer (score 9):

**TL;DR:** Reputation is calculated in temporal order of reputation inputs (votes etc.), using a saturating accumulator that saturates from below at 1.

A saturating odometer would be stuck at 999_999, saturating from above. Saturation is the opposite of wrap-around or rollover when you accumulate things.

Comment: This answer was more confusing than the others... something you don't typically find in a tl;dr

Comment: I have no idea whether this is true or right but it sounds awesome.

Comment: @ChaseSandmann I think everyone who programs knows what a saturating accumulator is, or they can quickly figure it out. Similarly, the word *temporal* shouldn't be problematic. So what is the problem? How can it be confusing? I'm more than willing to improve it, but please, don't hesitate to say how is it confusing.

Comment: @KubaOber I'd say that the your meaning, while apparent, isn't as readily obvious as some of the other answers due to your choice of vocabulary.  Keep in mind I don't mean this as a criticism.

Comment: @MichaelMcGriff Constructive criticism is fine. As far as I'm concerned, the vocabulary is basic, but if you can retain the meaning while using less "challenging" vocabulary, I'm all ears! I do want to improve this answer.

Comment: @MichaelMcGriff The saturation makes using certain phrases very confusing. For example, you can't say "in the temporal order of reputation changes" or "... reputation events", because some inputs don't change the reputation (saturation).

Comment: @KubaOber I didn't know what a saturating accumulator was by that name until I checked the Wiki.  IMO I don't think that term is common knowledge (maybe I'm just clueless which is another possibility) or that many people would bother to look it up.  +1 for making me look something up.

Comment: Dude we are not mathmaticians, write a tl;dr English people can understand, in fact what is a saturating accumulator: https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=saturating+accumulator&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:en-GB:official&client=firefox-a&channel=fflb&gfe_rd=cr&ei=veXtU_WZH8bH8gec94CwAg#channel=fflb&q=define+saturating+accumulator&rls=org.mozilla:en-GB:official ?

Comment: I didn't know what a saturating accumulator was, but still I did understand. These words are quite self-describing.

Comment: @BartoszKP something saturating "from below at 1" is self explanatory?

Comment: @Sammaye Of course it's subjective. For me "saturating accumulator that saturates from below at 1" is self explanatory. I guess the condition is to be familiar with the term "saturation" in the context of mathematical functions, but I remember this one from high school.

Comment: Had I not read the comments I would not believe that anyone who programs doesn't know what saturation is, and doesn't place it right opposite of wrap-around in their mental model of "things". Now the question is: are people unfamiliar with the name for the concept, or the concept itself. If it's the latter, I might need to drink tonight, even though I drink very rarely. If it's just the former, then I have attempted a fix.

Answer (score 4):

The code for the algorithm would be something like this:

```
public void downVote() {
    long newReputation = getCurrentReputation() - 2;
    if (newReputation < 1) { 
        newReputation = 1;
    }
    setCurrentReputation(newReputation);
}
```

Comment: I like that reputation is `long`. Sounds optimistic...

Comment: @user000001 I should have used BigInteger we never know :P

Comment: More amusing would be a 2 byte integer.  JonSkeet would be negative and positive on alternating months...